# Combine VALUE keyword with other SELECT Elements in Document DB

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to flatten a JSON document using the VALUE keyword combined with other specific fields without luck.

Given a Document DB document of:

```
{
    "id": "Tenant-Test",
    "name": "Test",
    "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
    "section1": {
        "section1Key1": "section 1 value 1",
        "section1Key2": "section 1 value 2",
        ...
    },
    "section2": {
        "section2Key1": "section 2 value 1"
    }
}
```

I want to get a subset of the data in the shape of:

```
{
    "id": "Tenant-Test",
    "name": "Test",
    "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
    "section1Key1": "section 1 value 1",
    "section1Key2": "section 1 value 2"
}
```

In theory I could query this with

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.timeZone, VALUE c.section1 FROM c
```

That gives a syntax error near 'VALUE'. If I remove the specific fields c.id, c.name, c.timeZone then I can flatten c.section1.

Is it possible to perform this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a UDF:

```
function transform(o) { 
  output = {}
  output.id = o.id
  output.name = o.name
  output.timeZone = o.timeZone
  output.section1Key1 = o.section1.section1Key1
  output.section1Key2 = o.section1.section1Key2
  return output 
}
```

You could replace the hard-coded section projections with loops that would flatten all no matter how wide or deep.

Then use the UDF in a query like this:

```
SELECT VALUE udf.transform(c) FROM collection c
```

Note, the keyword `VALUE` in the example above suppresses the $1 prefixes that are added before each document if you leave it out.

Comment: This works with the following loop:

    for (var key in o.section1) {
        if (o.section1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            output[key] = o.section1[key];
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to Aravind's is as below:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.timeZone, c.section1.section1Key1 AS section1Key1, c.section1.section1Key2 AS section1Key2 
FROM c
```

Comment: This works, but it was perhaps unclear in my question that I don't know the contents of the child section ahead of time.

Comment: Did Aravind delete his answer? Why?